# Use if condition in ascx file

Tags: asp.net, if-statement, ascx

Hi, I want to use `if condition` in .ascx file. As shown below:

```
<%= if (value.equals("xyz")) {}  %>
```

as shown above, if i use like that. then i am getting error of "`invalid expression if`".

please guide me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of `<%=` you should use `<%` (without the `=` sign):

```
<% if (value.equals("xyz")) { } %>
```

`<%=` is used when you want to output the result of the expression directly to the HTML.

Answer (score 5):

This is because the expression does not evaluate to a string, that can be included in the markup, so the `<%=`notation cannot be used. You can do it with the conditional operator:

```
<%= condition ? "value if true" : "value if false" %>
```

Or you can insert a code block using this notation:

```
<% if (value.equals("xyz")) { } %>
```

Just be aware that you then need to `Response.Write` any output you want within the curly braces. This is not best practice - try to avoid logic in your markup.

Answer (score 0):

Above answers can not be used for boolean atributes such as "Visible". Instead put this code in the BindData() function.

```
if (condition) {
    this.pnlMyPanel.Visible = true;
} else {
    this.pnlMyPanel.Visible = false;
}
```

If you don't tipically use BindData(), put it in Page_Load under

```
if (!this.IsPostBack) {}
```

block.